# How do I download my photostream photosto my laptop

Tags: photos, photo-stream

I was able to download my camera roll but not my photo stream. how do I download my photo stream?

Answer (score 1):

Credit: [Apple KB Artice](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317)

If you are on a Mac:

1. From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences.
2. Click iCloud. Then select Photos.
3. Click the Options button and make sure that My Photo Stream is turned on.
4. This should store them in the PhotoLibrary that is in your ~/Users/[User]/Pictures folder

On a PC:

1. Download and install iCloud for Windows.
2. Open iCloud for Windows.
3. Next to Photos, click Options.
4. Select My Photo Stream.
5. Click Done, then click Apply.
6. This should store them in your C:\Users[User]\Pictures\ folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up [iCloud on your computer](https://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html) (requires Vista SP2 or higher), then turn on Photo Stream.  You will only get photo stream photos from the last 30 days. If you want to stream older photos to your computer, create a shared photo stream containing the older photos and [invite yourself as a subscriber](https://help.apple.com/icloud/#mmc0cd7e99).